Imported Gradle-Android project not configured correctly in VSCode
I've downloaded several Android opensource projects and I've tried to import them into VSCode (VScodium, to be precise) and I'm having issues with the java classes.
The java classes are not appearing in Java Projects View.  I do see Kotlin classes (.kt) but no Java classes (.java)
My instinct tells me it must be related to the VSCode Gradle plugin. Although it is loading the config files and I'm able to run Gradle tasks successfully but it seems it is not recognizing the android project as java project (as src folders are not recognized as such and it is not loading the project dependencies).
I tried to add a "java" plugin and it causes conflict the android plugin.
I'm asking because maybe I'm missing something and I need a bit of guidance.
Cheers!
Progress part 1: I was able to force the "detection" of src folders, by configuring them manually inside the build.gradle file. Not ideal, but a step in the right direction. But the dependencies are still missing...
